# Arrange long-format dataframe according to multiple columns and taking into account changing sorting directions

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to re-arrange my data according to a score variable `value` and an additional `group` variable. However, depending on the `group` the sorting should either be descending or ascending. The groups are consisting of test scores (higher is better) and processing time (lower is better).

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, 4),
                 value = rnorm(16, 5), 
                 group = c(paste0("test", 1:3), "time0"))
df$value[seq(4,16, 4)] <- 1:4

> df %>% group_by(group) %>% arrange(group, desc(value))
# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   group [4]
      id value group
   <int> <dbl> <fct>
 1     3  6.06 test1
 2     4  4.69 test1
 3     1  4.32 test1
 4     2  3.56 test1
 5     4  5.96 test2
 6     1  5.96 test2
 7     3  4.43 test2
 8     2  3.86 test2
 9     3  6.28 test3
10     4  5.55 test3
11     2  4.59 test3
12     1  3.53 test3
13     4  4    time0
14     3  3    time0
15     2  2    time0
16     1  1    time0
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
      id value group
   <int> <dbl> <fct>
 1     3  6.06 test1
 2     4  4.69 test1
 3     1  4.32 test1
 4     2  3.56 test1
 5     4  5.96 test2
 6     1  5.96 test2
 7     3  4.43 test2
 8     2  3.86 test2
 9     3  6.28 test3
10     4  5.55 test3
11     2  4.59 test3
12     1  3.53 test3
13     4  1    time0
14     3  2    time0
15     2  3    time0
16     1  4    time0
```

I tried using `arrange_if` but could not figure it out.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks for the answers so far, they are equally helpful!

---

**EDIT for Clarification:** This is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns) question since the sorting is not only based on multiple columns but also dependend on within-column characteristics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes the rows within test groups sort descending and the rows within time groups sort ascending. If you want the inverse, just reverse the -1 and 1.

```
df %>% 
  arrange(group, value*ifelse(grepl('time', group), 1, -1))

#    id    value group
# 1   1 6.358680 test1
# 2   1 6.100025 test1
# 3   1 4.844204 test1
# 4   1 3.622940 test1
# 5   2 5.763176 test2
# 6   2 4.897212 test2
# 7   2 4.585005 test2
# 8   2 3.529248 test2
# 9   3 5.387672 test3
# 10  3 4.835476 test3
# 11  3 4.605710 test3
# 12  3 4.521850 test3
# 13  4 1.000000 time0
# 14  4 2.000000 time0
# 15  4 3.000000 time0
# 16  4 4.000000 time0
```

Here is another option which works when `value` is character

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, 4),
                 value = rnorm(16, 5), 
                 group = c(paste0("test", 1:3), "time0"))
set.seed(2019)
df$value <- sample(letters, nrow(df), T)

df %>% 
  arrange(group, rank(value)*ifelse(grepl('time', group), 1, -1))
#    id value group
# 1   1     u test1
# 2   1     f test1
# 3   1     c test1
# 4   1     b test1
# 5   2     s test2
# 6   2     p test2
# 7   2     f test2
# 8   2     b test2
# 9   3     v test3
# 10  3     u test3
# 11  3     s test3
# 12  3     h test3
# 13  4     a time0
# 14  4     q time0
# 15  4     q time0
# 16  4     r time0
```

Comment: Do you think this will also work when there are 2 positive and 2 negative values for `time` ?

Comment: Yes. Of course, it will not sort them based on absolute value, but it will sort them ascending or descending, according to the group, properly.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how this works, but it does work.

Comment: For groups where the `ifelse` returns `-1`, this sorts by `value*(-1)` = `-value`, i.e. sorts by value descending (sorting by -x is equivalent to sorting by x descending). For groups where `ifelse` returns `1`, this sorts by `value*1` = `value` i.e. sorts by value ascending.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is answering the question perfectly. Although, one potential issue might arise when `value` contains non-numerical data.

Comment: Added a method which works for non-numeric `value` field

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `filter` to exclude the 'time0' group, do the `arrange` on the rest of the dataset and `bind_rows` with the other set of group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(group != 'time0') %>%
   arrange(group, desc(value)) %>%
   bind_rows(., df %>% 
                  filter(group == 'time0') %>% 
                  arrange(value))
#   id value group
#1   3  6.06 test1
#2   4  4.69 test1
#3   1  4.32 test1
#4   2  3.56 test1
#5   4  5.96 test2
#6   1  5.96 test2
#7   3  4.43 test2
#8   2  3.86 test2
#9   3  6.28 test3
#10  4  5.55 test3
#11  2  4.59 test3
#12  1  3.53 test3
#13  1  1.00 time0
#14  2  2.00 time0
#15  3  3.00 time0
#16  4  4.00 time0
```

---

Also, if the 'value' can be non-numeric'

```
df %>%
    arrange(group, desc(as.numeric(value)), is.na(as.numeric(value)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), value = c(6.06, 4.69, 4.32, 3.56, 5.96, 
5.96, 4.43, 3.86, 6.28, 5.55, 4.59, 3.53, 4, 3, 2, 1), group = c("test1", 
"test1", "test1", "test1", "test2", "test2", "test2", "test2", 
"test3", "test3", "test3", "test3", "time0", "time0", "time0", 
"time0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is neat solution and answers my question completely. Additionally, it will also work in the case when `df$value[seq(4,16, 4)] <- letters[1:4]`.